# Creating multiple Alias records in Terraform with for_each

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, terraform, alias

I am trying to create multiple alias DNS records in terraform using for_each. I am getting an error when specifying the name and zone ID of the Alias name. My question is how do I read from a variable defined as a set of strings? Below is my code block and variables defined:

```
    resource "aws_route53_record" "alias_records" {
      for_each = var.alias_names
      zone_id  = aws_route53_zone.zone.zone_id
      name     = each.key
      type     = "A"
    
      alias {
        name                   = var.alias_dns_names[each.key]
        zone_id                = var.alias_zone_ids[each.key]
        evaluate_target_health = false
      }
    }

    variable "alias_names" {
      type = set(string)
    }
    variable "alias_dns_names" {
      type = set(string)
    }
    variable "alias_zone_ids" {
      type = set(string)
    }
```

```
    Error: Invalid index

      on alias.tf line 8, in resource "aws_route53_record" "alias_records":
       8:     name                   = var.alias_dns_names[each.key]
    
    This value does not have any indices.
    
    
    Error: Invalid index
    
      on alias.tf line 9, in resource "aws_route53_record" "alias_records":
       9:     zone_id                = var.alias_zone_ids[each.key]
    
    This value does not have any indices.
```

```
    alias_names = [
      "alias1",
      "alias2",
      "alias3"
    }

    alias_dns_names = [
      "alias_dns_1",
      "alias_dns_2",
      "alias_dns_3"
    }

    alias_zone_ids = [
      "alias_zone_1",
      "alias_zone_2",
      "alias_zone_3"
    }
```

Comment: What do your variable inputs look like for this situation?

Comment: I have my inputs in a .tfvars file. I will update with the inputs.

Comment: So you are iterating through one list and trying to access values from another two lists. It seems like you want a `Map` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set data structure is not ordered and its elements don't have any identifiers other than their values, so the set type is not appropriate for your use-case here.

Since you seem to be describing three different aspects of the same underlying object here, I think the most convenient way to expose that from your module would be as a map of objects, like this:

```
variable "aliases" {
  type = map(object({
    zone_id  = string
    dns_name = string
  }))
}
```

You can then use this variable alone to capture all three of the values you need for each alias record:

```
  aliases = {
    alias1 = {
      zone_id  = "alias_zone_1"
      dns_name = "alias_dns_1"
    }
    alias2 = {
      zone_id  = "alias_zone_2"
      dns_name = "alias_dns_2"
    }
    alias3 = {
      zone_id  = "alias_zone_3"
      dns_name = "alias_dns_3"
    }
  }
```

A map of any data type can be used directly with resource `for_each`, with `each.key` representing the map key and `each.value` representing the value. So you can then change your resource block like this:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "alias_records" {
  for_each = var.aliases
  zone_id  = aws_route53_zone.zone.zone_id
  name     = each.key
  type     = "A"

  alias {
    zone_id                = each.value.zone_id
    name                   = each.value.dns_name
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}
```

Because the elements of the map are objects, you can access them from `each.value` to get the `zone_id` and `dns_name` values that correspond with each key in the original map.

Comment: Thank you @MartinAtinks. This helps a lot. Quick question, if I have multiple values for one key in a map, how would I specify that. I am trying to set one route53 record with two values and am getting an error specifying "The given value is not valid for variable "example": element "example": attribute "example": string required. The attribute has the correct data type of string, but for some reason it is outputting an error.

Comment: I think I'd need to see a fuller example to answer that. If you post a new question about it and include a full example and error message (as you did here) then I'll look out for it and try to answer it.

Comment: I tried some things and posted a new question if you can take a look. Thank you again for your help.